# Is there anyway to store data which is being recieved at a frequency of 20000 data points/second such a wat that it can be accessed parallely

Tags: python, opc-ua

I am currently connected to OPC Server using python and I'm receiving data at a high frequency , I want to store it such a way that there is no loss of data. I also want to access it in parallel so that I can send it to an ANN.

I tried using `to_csv` but 90% of the points are not being saved.

Comment: UDP or TCP?. It's hard to say what's causing packet loss...You have to figure out uisng packet sniffer like Wireshark

Comment: You should tell use more about your architecture. It could be a good idea to make async your disk writes or to bufferize your received data, i.e. your Python client fill a blocking queue and another process (or thread) consumes the queue and writes to disk.
What's  `to_csv` ? a pandas method ?

Comment: use threads. one thread to read points and another one to store them at regular intervals

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.